# Upload a picture after the upload button hidden

Tags: upload, vuejs3, element-ui

```
<style>
.hide .el-upload {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

```
<el-upload
            class="w-2d5 upload-box"
            :class="{hide:upLoadHide}"
            action=""
            accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
            :on-preview="handlePreview"
            :on-remove="handleRemove"
            :http-request="customUpload"
            :file-list="fileList"
            list-type="picture-card"
            :limit="1"
            :on-change="handleChange"
          >
            <div>
              <el-icon><Plus /></el-icon>
            </div>
          </el-upload>
```

```
const handleChange = () => {
  upLoadHide.value = true 
}
const handleRemove = () => {
  upLoadHide.value = false
}
```

Now this is done, but adding a new image does not show the upload button
[dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5XL6.png)

Add new picture display upload button

Comment: Your code is not full enough to understand your problem. Please provide more code with details about your HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide us with more details to help you with your problem.

Here is the working playground with Element+ Upload Control.

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const fileList = ref([]);
    const upLoadHide = ref(false);
    const handleChange = () => {
      upLoadHide.value = true 
    }
    const handleRemove = () => {
      upLoadHide.value = false
    }
    const handlePreview = () => {      
    }    
    const customUpload = () => {      
    }    
    return {
      fileList,
      upLoadHide,
      handleChange,
      handleRemove,
      handlePreview,
      customUpload
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.hide .el-upload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css" />
<div id="app"> 
    <el-upload
            class="w-2d5 upload-box"
            :class="{hide:upLoadHide}"
            action=""
            accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
            :on-preview="handlePreview"
            :on-remove="handleRemove"
            :http-request="customUpload"
            :file-list="fileList"
            list-type="picture-card"
            :limit="1"
            :on-change="handleChange"
          >
            <div>
              <el-icon><Plus /></el-icon>
            </div>
          </el-upload>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
```